# Help em plugin ou função

Tags: wordpress, funções, plugin-wordpress

Alguém sabe de um plugin ou função que deleta automaticamente depois de um certo período postagens e mídias do Wordpress?

Tenho um site de notícias e tem notícias de mais de 2 anos que desejo deletar, pois pesa e não tem nenhuma vantagem de manter no servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Darlei te sugiro o Bulk Delete. https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-delete/

Aqui é o projeto deles no GitHub https://github.com/sudar/bulk-delete

README: https://github.com/sudar/bulk-delete/blob/master/README.md

*Ele tem algumas funções pagas, mas para o que vc precisa não precisa ser Pro (pago)* Qualquer dúvida veja o ReadMe dele no link acima.

> Nele tem vária opções de gerenciar o conteúdo antigo. Deletar, ou só mover pra Lixeira. Configurar datas para remoção de conteúdo etc.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito interessante - A função que quero das imagens é paga rs

Comment: Se fosse possível o Wordpress não criar um monte de miniaturas seriam bom, uma imagem de 70kb ao fazer upload cria um monte de versões que chega a 1 mb, imagina um site com mais de 100 notícias diárias.

Comment: @DarleiCordeiro cara da uma pesquisada na plataforma do WordPress do StackExchange https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ lá deve ter alguma coisa free que resolva. E o WP cria esse tanto de imagem pq ele usa um tipo de Srcset para criar uma imagem pra cada resolução de tela, então o usuário só faz o download da imagem ideal pra tela dele.

Comment: Claro vou olhar sim @hugocsl

Comment: Comprei o plugin para conferir ele, porém clico em ativar e não está ativando ~~

Comment: @DarleiCordeiro da uma olhada no site oficial deles https://bulkwp.com/ lá tem a documentação. Aqui tem um artigo que pode te ajudar https://wpmayor.com/clean-up-your-website-bulkwp-coms/ e no repositório do WP tem a página de Suporte que parece que respondem direitinho https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/bulk-delete